# Test Angular. TypeError: this._platformStrategy.getBaseHref is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test routing. I tried this script:

```
describe('Router: App', () => {
    let location: Location;
    let router: Router;
    let fixture;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AlarmsTableComponent,
                AddAlarmsFormComponent,
                EditAlarmsFormComponent,
                LoginComponent,
                DataFilterPipe
            ],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, DataTableModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, HttpModule],
            providers: [Location, LocationStrategy, AlarmsService, DataFilterPipe, AuthService, ConnectionBackend, HttpModule,
                {
                    provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/page' }
                ]
        });

        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        location = TestBed.get(Location);

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
        router.initialNavigation();
    });
    it('navigate to "" redirects you to /page', fakeAsync(() => {
        router.navigate(['page']);
        tick();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/page');
    }));
});
```

When I `ng test` the result is this error:

> TypeError: this._platformStrategy.getBaseHref is not a function

Edit:

```
describe('Router: App', () => {
    let location: Location;
    let router: Router;
    let fixture;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AlarmsTableComponent,
                AddAlarmsFormComponent,
                EditAlarmsFormComponent,
                LoginComponent,
                DataFilterPipe
            ],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, DataTableModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, HttpModule],
 providers: [Location, AuthService, AlarmsService, DataFilterPipe,
            {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }],
        });

        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        location = TestBed.get(Location);

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
        router.initialNavigation();
    });
    it('navigate to "" redirects you to /page', fakeAsync(() => {
        router.navigate(['page']);
        tick();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/page');
    }));
});
```

And now show this:

> Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF
>   token or add a base element to the document.

Comment: Can you show us where you initialize `_platformStrategy` ?

Comment: I have not initialized it

Answer (score 4):

First, remove `HttpModule` in `providers`. He must not be there, just in `imports`.

Modify the way you provide `LocationStrategy`, like this :

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/page' }
```

See more on [PathLocationStrategy official doc](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy).

Comment: I change it, and now show this error: `Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.`

Comment: Don't remove `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/page' }`.

From the official doc: "If you're using PathLocationStrategy, you must provide a APP_BASE_HREF"

Comment: In routing.ts I have this   `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'page' }` When I click in testing, show NOT FOUND.